# How to use azure-cli node package in Node js application

Tags: node.js, azure, package, azure-cli

I am developing a Node js application. I want to use the azure-cli package in my application to create HDI cluster and VM.

```
npm install azure-cli -g --save
```

Above command install the azure-cli v1.0 only.

How and where should I use the azure commands in my application.

Should I need write azure cli commands in shell script file and call that script file from node js application or any other way like calling azure cli commands in the node js application without a script file?

Note: Why [azure-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-cli) doesn't install azure cli V2.0

Update 1:-

If I install [winston](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston) package application, I can use like the following

```
 var winston = require('winston');

  winston.log('info', 'Hello distributed log files!');
  winston.info('Hello again distributed logs');
```

Like that, Is there a way to use if I install [azure-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-cli)? (i.e inside my node js application)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your specific question around creating a VM or HDI (Hadoop cluster) in your Node.js app, the best approach would be to use the Azure SDK for Node.

1. For VMs, use `npm install azure-arm-compute` and follow instructions in [VM Modules for NodeJS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/azure/virtualmachines?view=azure-node-latest)
2. For Hadoop, use `npm install azure-arm-hdinsight` and follow reference for [azure-arm-hdinsight package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-arm-hdinsight/index?view=azure-node-latest)

The older version of the Azure CLI was Node.js based, while the current version of the Azure CLI (v2) is Python based. You can install the latest version via the multiple mechanisms provided in http://aka.ms/cli.